# Loop Find function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have this code who is searching Dates in big text in severals cells (Column A).
The probleme is that sometimes the number of dates can reach 400 !!
I can't repeat this code for 400 values !

The aim of the code is :

```
Find("Date d'Evaluation(1):"), copy/past in B5 (-22 car)
Find("Date d'Evaluation(2):"), copy/past in C5 (-22 car)
Find("Date d'Evaluation(3):"), copy/past in D5 (-22 car)
…
…
```

the code is :

```
Dim Date1 As Range
Dim Date2 As Range
Dim Date3 As Range

''''''' trouver les dates d'observation
Set Date1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A500").Find("Date d'Evaluation(1):")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B5").Value = Date1.Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B5").Value = Right(Date1.Value, Len(Date1.Value) - 22) 'enelve le surplu

Set Date2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A500").Find("Date d'Evaluation(2):")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C5").Value = Date2.Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C5").Value = Right(Date2.Value, Len(Date2.Value) - 22) 'enelve le surplu

Set Date3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A500").Find("Date d'Evaluation(3):")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5").Value = Date3.Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5").Value = Right(Date3.Value, Len(Date3.Value) - 22) 'enelve le surplu
```

After searching on google, the mains questions are:

- Can I loop `Dim Date(n) As range` ?
- Can I loop until it don't find ("Date d'Evaluation(n):") ? Then stop
  the loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all in one loop. The loop runs until nothing is found:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProcedureName()
    Dim RangeToSearch As Range
    Set RangeToSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    Do
        Dim FoundRange As Range
        Set FoundRange = RangeToSearch.Find(What:="Date d'Evaluation(" & i & "):", LookAt:=xlPart)

        If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            Dim FoundDate As Variant
            FoundDate = Split(Right$(FoundRange.Value, Len(FoundRange.Value) - 22), "/")

            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B5").Offset(ColumnOffset:=i - 1).Value = DateSerial(FoundDate(2), FoundDate(1), FoundDate(0))
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop Until FoundRange Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that it is necessary to include `LookAt:=xlPart` in the `Find` method. Otherwise Excel uses the method that was last used by Excel (and you never know which one this was).

I used `Split` to split the found date eg `02/04/2024` into an array:

```
FoundDate(0) = "02"
FoundDate(1) = "04"
FoundDate(2) = "2024"
```

so we can convert it into a real date with `DateSerial`

- `DateSerial(FoundDate(2), FoundDate(1), FoundDate(0))` for `DD/MM/YYYY`
- `DateSerial(FoundDate(2), FoundDate(0), FoundDate(1))` for `MM/DD/YYYY`

Comment: Your code is working but as amazing it can be, the "Date d'Evaluation(6): 02/04/2024" is 04/02/2024 in G5 !! all the other dates are correct. It's picked from a text how can it change this ? EDIT : it's when -22 car is too much. sometimes it's 21... but then there is space in front of all dates and last date have ":" like ": 29/03/2028"

Comment: @babou Is your date meant to be `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`?

Comment: see my edit comment. maybe one line of code for delete all space in the row 5 and another one to delete ":" ?

Comment: @babou try `FoundDate = Split(Right$(FoundRange.Value, Len(FoundRange.Value) - InStrRev(FoundRange.Value, " ")), "/")`  or just `FoundDate = Split(Right$(FoundRange.Value, 10), "/")` in my edited code above.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...my post is almost identical to Pᴇʜ's.  Oh well, I did add a couple of twists.

`LookAt:=xlPart` is needed so that find will search partial values of the cells.
I used `LookIn:=xlValues` because I constructed my dataset using formulas.

The idea is to add all the found values to an ArrayList and write them back to Sheet2 in one operation.

```
Sub UpdateDEvaluation()
    Dim list As Object, Found As Range, Source As Range
    Dim n As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Source = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Do
        n = n + 1

        Set Found = Source.Find(What:="Date d'Evaluation(" & n & "):", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            list.Add Right(Found.Value, Len(Found.Value) - 22)
        End If

    Loop Until Found Is Nothing

    If list.Count > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D5").Resize(1, list.Count).Value = list.ToArray
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following, it will loop up to 400 times, and stop looping when nothing is found:

```
Sub foo()
Dim Date1 As Range
For i = 1 To 400
    FindValue = "Date d'Evaluation(" & i & "):"
''''''' trouver les dates d'observation
    Set Date1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A500").Find(What:=FindValue, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not Date1 Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(5, i + 1).Value = Right(Date1.Value, Len(Date1.Value) - 22) 'enelve le surplu
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```